# javascript button does not appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I am stack with having a button working. It is a button created only in javascript. The site is kind of a data(JSON file), so there is a staff.When someone try to make a search, e.g Search for staff in brach based in London and salary more than 24K, when clicking the button, all members of staff relevant for this search will appear one after another.

```
for(var i in data.staff){
    if( ( branchType == data.staff[i].type ) || (branchType == "Any") ) {
        output += "<p>" + data.staff[i].type + " $" + data.staff[i].salary +"</p>"  +  "<a href=" + data.staff[i].url + "><p>
<img src=" + data.staff[i].picture + "></a>" + data.staff[i].description + 
("button") + "</p>";
    }
}
```

I want a button to be presented after every staff member that has been sorted by the search, so I cannot really implement it in the HTML?
This is what I have:

```
        function createButton(context, func){
            var button = document.createElement("input");
            button.type = "button";
            button.value = "im a button";
            button.onclick = func;
            output.appendChild(button);
        }
    button.addEventListener("click",function(){
 alert("did something");
 });
```

But it does not really work. What I get printed on the page is: button
Any idea?

Comment: You aren't calling `createButton()` anywhere in that code. And `output` is a string. You can't `appendChild` to a string.

Comment: What is the actual code since you have syntax errors in what you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice that you had jquery in your question tags, so I presume you want to use it.

The code bellow add a button following each staff item.

There is a on click event attached to each button.

When you click on the button you get an alert with the message : do something.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click','input.staff-button',function() {
        alert('do something');
    });

    var output = '';
    for (var i in data.staff) {
        if ((branchType === data.staff[i].type) || (branchType === "Any")) {
            output += '<div class="staff-item-'+i+'">';
            output += '<p>' + data.staff[i].type + ' $' + data.staff[i].salary +'</p>';
            output += '<p><a href="' + data.staff[i].url + '"><img src="' + data.staff[i].picture + '"></a></p>';
            output += '<p>' + data.staff[i].description +  '</p>';
            output += '<p><input type="button" id="staff-'+i.toString()+'" class="staff-button" /></p>';
            output += '</div>';
        }
    }
    $('body').append(output);
});
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the code is complete because there are several errors.
eg:

output not defined in function

button.addEventListener outside button scope

But you need something like this and call it for every row in list:

```
function createButton(parentDomElement, func)
{
  var button = document.createElement("input");
  button.type = "button";
  button.value = "im a button";
  button.onclick = func;
  parentDomElement.appendChild(button);
}
```

and your "rendering" loop needs to create a DOM element and call the button function.

```
for(var i in data.staff)
{
    if( ( branchType == data.staff[i].type ) || (branchType == "Any") )
    {
       // Create paragraph DOM element and set content to your data and the call
       // createButton(domElement, func);
    }
}
```